# Option to copy lines with carets NOT separated with empty lines

Tags: sublimetext2

Sublime text 2 (Windows 7) has such feature: several lines with carets (no selections made,only carets) are copied to Clipboard separated with empty lines. Can i disable these empty line separators, to copy w/o them?

detail:

- open few lines text file
- place 3-4 carets using Ctrl+Click on few lines
- press Ctrl+C to copy to clibboard
- paste into new file-- u see empty line separators for copied text

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're describing here. Could you add a screenshot or two?

Comment: That clarifies things; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Think you need a plugin to do it. I didn't test this, but it should work. It's pretty straight forward.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class EmptyLineCopyCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        lines = []
        for cursor in view.sel():
            lines.append(view.substr(view.line(cursor)))
        sublime.set_clipboard("\n".join(lines))
```

Put the following in your user key bindings.

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+c"], "command": "empty_line_copy", "context": [
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
]},
```